# Get AnonymousID in Razor

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want get `HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID` of users in `Razor` and then send it to an action in a controller in this way:

```
<script>
 app.controller('loginController', function ($http, $scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.login = function () {

        //Send Anonymous to UserLogin action
        $http.post("/Accounts/UserLogin?anonymous="+AnonymousId, $scope.model).success(function (response) {
            $scope.message = response;

            window.location = '/';
            $rootScope.ShowSpinner = false;
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It seems that `AnonymousID` is a session parameter, so why do you need to send it back explicitly to the server? The server already knows it?

Answer (score 0):

In razor you can have something like

```
@{
    // Just to make my expression smaller
    var anonymousId = HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID;
}
<script>
    angular.module("someModule").value("anonymousId", "@anonymousId" );
</script>
```

Note injecting Razor is just normal. If it fails, try wrapping in `()`, like `"@(anonymousId)"`. The only trick is that I just wrapped the value in quotes so that it's a string in JavaScript.

Then you can inject this value into your Angular controller:

```
<script>
 app.controller('loginController', 
        function ($http, $scope, $location, $rootScope, anonymousId) {
            $scope.login = function () {

            //Send Anonymous to UserLogin action
            $http.post("/Accounts/UserLogin?anonymous="+anonymousId, $scope.model)
                .success(function (response) {
                    ...
            });
       }
});
</script>
```

Of course you can also write it directly in the controller as well...

```
....
    $http.post("/Accounts/UserLogin?anonymous=" 
              + "@(HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID)", $scope.model).
....
```